# Is there an explicit formula for this recursive series of matrices

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, recursion, diagonalization

I want to get an efficient way of computing $P_k$ from $P_0$ that satisfies the following recursion:

$P_k = FP_{k-1}F^T+Q$

Where $P_k$, $F$ and $Q$ are matrices ($Q$ is diagonal, if it changes anything).

We can get the following explicit formula:

$P_k = F^kP_0(F^T)^k+\sum _{i=0}^{k-1}F^iQ(F^T)^i$

Where the first term can be easily computed by diagonalization, but the series in the second term seems tough !

Comment: By analogy with solving the scalar recurrence $x_n = ax_{n-1}+b$ by setting $y_n = x_n+b/(a-1)$, so that $y_n=ay_{n-1}$, I'd like to do something like set $R_k = P_k + (F-I)^{-1}Q(F^T-I)^{-1}$. But that doesn't quite work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, the first term can be easily computed by diagonalization. If $F = T\Lambda T^{-1}$, then
$$ P_k = T\Lambda^k T^{-1} P_0 T^{-T}\Lambda^k T^T + \sum_{i=0}^k T\Lambda^i T^{-1} Q T^{-T}\Lambda^i T^T $$
You can simplify this slightly to
$$ P_k = T\Lambda^k T^{-1} P_0 T^{-T}\Lambda^k T^T + T \left[ \sum_{i=0}^k \Lambda^i \tilde{Q} \Lambda^i \right] T^T $$
where $\tilde Q = T^{-1} Q T^{-T}$.
Now note that each term of the series is a matrix $\tilde Q$ with row and column scalings governed by $\Lambda^{i}$. In particular, each element of that matrix is of the form $\lambda_p^i \lambda_q^{i} \tilde{Q}_{pq}$. You can apply the [geometric series summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) to each element separately.

Comment: turns out that my matrix $F$ is not diagonalizable after all, but if you do make that assumption you are entirely correct !

Comment: Why is $F$ not diagonalizable? That usually makes it easier to compute.